# How get content Height in webview

Tags: android, webview, height

I want to get content height of webView and I used `webView.getHeight()` but it is return height of webview not content height.
This is my code :

```
webView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {

                Log.i("pageHeight", webView.getContentHeight()+"");
                webView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);

            }
        });
```

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can set using JavaScript, the following link may help you.
https://capdroid.wordpress.com/2014/08/07/resizing-webview-to-match-the-content-size/